# How to redirect during OnTicketReceived

Tags: c#, openid-connect, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-middleware

In our OIDC flow I have this method...

```
    options.Events.OnTicketReceived = async context =>
    {
      ...
        (bool doRedirect, string destUrl) = redirectHelper.ProcessRedirectionRules(user);
        if (doRedirect)
        {
          context.Response.Redirect(destUrl);
          return;
        }
      
      ...
    };
```

Unfortunately, though I really need to redirect the user to a destination URL, the `context.Response.Redirect(destUrl);` does not perform a redirection at all.

Am I attempting to redirect in the wrong place or in the wrong way? How should this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're missing this:

```cs
if (doRedirect)
{
  context.Response.Redirect(destUrl);
  context.HandleResponse();
  return;
}
```

Summary:
Discontinue all processing for this request and return to the client. The caller is responsible for generating the full response.